# "A graph with $n \ge 2$ vertices has at least two vertices with same degree". Is there a generalization of this fact?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Namely, I'm looking for something along the lines of

> If $k = \chi(G)$, then there exists $k$ disjoint subsets of vertices $S_1, \dots, S_k$ such that
>   $$
> \sum_{v \in S_i} d(v)
> $$
>   is constant, for all $i$.

where, $d(v)$ is the degree of vertex $v$.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by $\chi(G)$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur, the chromatic number of $G$.

Comment: I may have confused myself, but what you wrote seems to be true when $S_i$is an equivalence class of vertices. What you wrote just seems to be the sum of degrees in said equivalence class.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Saying that "$S_i$ is an equivalence class of vertices" doesn't make sense until you've specified the equivalence relation.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Given any equivalence relation on the vertices with $k$ equivalence classes, isn't this true? For example given a coloring $f:V\rightarrow [k]$, does this not hold automatically?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur The equivalence classes of an arbitrary equivalence relation can be absolutely anything - and in particular, don't necessarily satisfy this condition. Neither is the condition true for the color classes of a proper coloring.

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood what the desired statement was.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest counter-example to your statement is $K_5-e$: the complete graph on $5$ vertices, with one edge deleted (or the skeleton graph of a [triangular bipyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_bipyramid)).

[image]

(Image source: [House of Graphs](https://houseofgraphs.org/graphs/450))

The chromatic number is $4$, but the vertex degrees are $3, 3, 4, 4, 4$, from which we cannot make more than $3$ subsets with equal sum.